# flex controlling application sound

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I have a flex application in which multiple sound files are used in various parts of the application. 
Can i have a single sound handler, which will take care of volume control fo the entire application at once. 
How can i do that

Answer (score 1):

In order to control the volume globally ,  you can use the SoundMixer class.

```
  private function set volume(level:Number ):void
  {
       var transform:SoundTransform = SoundMixer.soundTransform;
       transform.volume = level;
  }
```

http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/

A Singleton class may be a little overkill since you only really need the above function to control the volume of the Sound globally.

Answer (score 0):

sure you can.
I would use a singleton pattern here.

something like:

```
SoundManager.getInstance().setVolume(volumeLevel:Number);
SoundManager.getInstance().playSound(soundName:String);

//sounds - class refeance or MP3 path or something else
SoundManager.GONG;
SoundManager.SQUASH
```

if you have an application needs to play sounds, this is the way I would handle it, it's the best way IMHO.